# Update values by shifting 1 row in Pandas

Tags: python

On sparse matrix on pandas dataframe, I want to update values where values are 1 by shifting one row.

```
from
   0  1  2
0  0  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  0
5  1  1  0

to
   0  1  2
0  0  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
5  1  1  0
```

I understand that updating values in a certain location is given by `table[table==1] = 1`

I don't want to use for sentence because it has huge number of records.

Comment: Your example contradicts your description: you seem to update 0's, not 1's. Also, `table[table==1] = 1` is doing exactly nothing.

Comment: Yes, table[table==1] = 1 is basically nothing, just replacing 1 to 1 on the same location. I wondered if it can shift 1's to next row. Other 0s are protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
newdf = df.shift().fillna(0).astype(int) | df
#   0  1  2
#0  0  1  1
#1  1  1  1
#2  1  1  0
#3  0  0  1
#4  0  0  1
#5  1  1  0
```

Comment: this answer is not correct IMO as in his example, he has replaced 0 with 1 if the element in the previous row same index position is 1

Comment: @satnam That's exactly what my proposed solution does.

Comment: I want to replace 0 to 1 when previous row has 1.

Comment: @DZY, check out the second row in Lcy's example. It is not all 0s, still it needs to be changed